# Save PDF file using webform2pdf

Tags: 7, webforms, forms, files

I am using Drupal 7.12 and [Webform2PDF 7.x-3.0](http://drupal.org/project/webform2pdf). Is there any feature to save the PDF file to server using this module? Or how can I do this with this module? Or is there any other module ?

Comment: Reading the Modules's documentation is a Drupal best practice.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot save it on the server. One way would be to create your own code to grab the pdf with a tool like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and save it to the server. You could trigger your code to run every time a webform is submitted throught [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules). You could issue a feature request to the module developer in case he wants add this fuctionality.

There is also this module: [Fill PDF](http://drupal.org/project/fillpdf) that does what you require. It is quite harder to get it to work with Webforms since you need to build your own pdf form template.

Comment: Why cant i save the file to server ?

Comment: @Nikhil Mohan Because webform2pdf creates a page that when you visit it renders the pdf at that time. Like I said other modules like Fill PDF give the user the option to save the pdf to the server. Other modules like Views PDF allow you to save the pdf to the server using Rules. This module does not offer this functionality to do it **automatically**.

Comment: Please take a look at the doc, hope you're a developer.

Comment: @Nikhil Mohan  Not sure I understand your attitude. Have you used the module? If there is a way to save the file to the server automatically then please share it as I am also interested. As I said the pdf file does not exist in the server. It is rendered when you request the download pdf page. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I accept my bad. Thanks for your notification. And i am not a bad guy.

Comment: @Perisdr Thank you. Can I mail the pdf to mail ids I manually enter. I mean ids other than in email configured in webform settings?

Comment: @SethuLakshmy Not sure what exactly you mean. You can mail the pdf to as many recipients you want by adding them through the webform settings. If you don't want all recipients to get the attached pdf then go to the Generate PDF settings and under E-mail Settings you can explicitly select which e-mail addresses should not receive the pdf.

Answer (score -2):

Have you read the documentation ? It states

> The Webform2PDF Drupal module is an extension of the Webform module.
>   It can be used to generate PDF document from the results of a form.
>   The generated PDF document can be attached to the form summary e-mail
>   sent by Webform module, or **it can be downloaded from the /Results/
>   page.**

As it can be downloaded it should be in your server. You can access it by typing the URL for sure.

See [Webform2PDF Module Users' Guide](https://www.niif.hu/en/webform2pdf_module_users_guide)